# Wizard out of Eclipse for drawing jBPM

Tags: java, jbpm

I saw that jBPM workflow has plugin-in for Eclipse to draw the processes (workflow)

Is there a way to draw the workflow out of Eclipse?

Comment: I don't think so, but without other solution a workaroud would be to create a 'light' eclipse containing only the jBPM plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a web-based BPMN process editor that comes with JBPM.  It's called Signavio.  If you installed jbpm into tomcat or JBoss AS using the install script, you can access the application by going to http://localhost:8080/jbpmeditor/p/explorer .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no non-Eclipse based jBPM designer.

However there is a [step by step instructions](http://brianbruijn.wordpress.com/2007/08/20/jbpm-and-eclipse/) how to configure it in Eclipse